# C# WPF Program Relase not working on other computers

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, exe

This may be a noobish question, but suppose I have a genereated exe from a program I ran in release mode on VS 2015, if I want to send my program to another computer, of course I send the Release folder (that has all of the appropriate DLLs + the main exe).. But does the user on the other computer **have** to have Visual Studios 2015 run my exe? If so, should I just make it so my program is actually installed on the other computer? It seems that when I send my exe to a computer that only has VS 2012 it doesn't want to run, but when I sent my exe to a computer with VS 2015 it will run.. Is this just coincidence perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've generated the .exe in VS 2015, it has probably compiled using .NET 4.5.1 or above. This will not be the case for VS 2012. You need to either: compile your program against an earlier version of the .NET framework, which you can do in the project's properties. Or, find out what version of the .NET framework you need, and make sure the client system has that .NET framework installed.

Comment: So essentially my client is screwed if they don't have the updated .NET framework correct?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can target your application to compile against the clients .NET framework. If you've used a few of the new features, you might need to port it over, but it shouldn't be too arduous.

Comment: Because we are 'assuming' that the client who uses our product of course does not have Visual Studios installed at all. So i'm thinking we need to find out how to somehow install OUR .NET framework via the clients computer when they install our program.

Comment: You just need to install the .NET framework, you do not need Visual Studio. For example, https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42643. Include the .NET framework as a prerequisite.

Comment: Awesome, that fixed the problem! Thanks Leigh!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to have VS instaled on client computer, neither 2012 nor 2015. All you need to ensure is that the computer have the same NET framework as your project has. For instance, if you project use Framework 4.0, you sen the release folder content and if that computer has the framework installed it should work. You must also check App.Config for your connection string if you are using a database.